# email spam filering in bridging

Tags: linux, email, spam, bridge

I've a mail server, which handle multiple domains. Due to concern of spam and mail server performance. I've configured another machine which will be in bridging and mail server would be behind that it.

How can i filter spam emails in bridging server without running any smtp services.

Scenario

Internet  +------+ Spamfilter Server (in bridging mode) +---------+ MailServer

SmartHost will work for outgoing email. In this scenario i can filter all incoming emails. There is also another option of DNS which i don't want to use.

Comment: I don't want to use untangle, I already know about it. I want to setup my own server so Can anyone please guide me for the technique being used by untangle spam blocker or spam filtering in bridging mode.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to set things up this way -- makes more sense to have your smarthost / mail filter receive mail (ideally have your WAN firewall port-forward SMTP traffic to it in the DMZ) and then configure it to relay to your mail server.

Check out [MailCleaner](http://www.mailcleaner.org/doku.php/downloads:latest) as a good, full-featured (+ free!) mail filter distro -- makes installation, configuration and management very easy.  Current version is at 'Beta 3', but it has been stable and production-worthy for over a year.

If you're looking to filter mail transparently without setting up a relay, you could try [Untangle -- the lite version is free](http://www.untangle.com/Lite-Package) and more advanced functionality and support can be purchased.  It can be configured on a multi-homed system to filter mail transparently.

Comment: I don't want to use untangle, I already know about it. I want to setup my own server so Can anyone please guide me for the technique being used by untangle spam blocker or spam filtering in bridging mode

Comment: Untangle is built on [debian](http://www.debian.org).  Looks like its spam filtering is built on [SpamAssassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/) with some other stuff configured as well: http://www.untangle.com/Spam-Blocker/Tech-Specs

Comment: [Here's some guidance](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ap-bridge-fw.en.html) for configuring iptables on debian for bridging.  I assume you're looking for something closer to D2 in this document, but if you're putting this thing at the network edge you'll definitely want some firewalling and possibly NAT.

Comment: Yes I'm looking for thing like D2, but still i could not get any idea