# Spam filtering in bridging

Tags: linux, sendmail, spam, bridge

I'm using sendmail with spamassasin, one of my server is working behind it. All the port 25 traffic for the server behind it is being filtered.

User are using SMTP authentication enabled in Microsoft Outlook 2007 or 2010. All user has to face error "none of the authentication methods are supported by your server".

Is there any way that I could filter Spam in bridging without breaking authentication?

Comment: I really dont understand your problem, can you describe it a little more detailed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [email spam filering in bridging](http://serverfault.com/questions/268384/email-spam-filering-in-bridging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach may be to setup a "dummy" account on the SMTP server answering on port 25. The users can then configure the Outlook clients with the credentials matching that of the "dummy" account for SMTP authentication.

Comment: Mail server is having many of virtual domains. Spam filtering is being used to protect users from spam.

Comment: One or multiple "dummy" accounts can be setup for each of the hosted virtual domains.